# Woocommerce if product category equal to "X" do job

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

I need a php code for my woocommerce plugin.
I'm trying to find out

```
if(product category = "xxxxx")
{
dojob
} else {
do other job
}
```

What should I do? I could not find similar topics

Comment: The provided pseudo code and related details are not enough… Are you targeting a product category page or product categories that is set for a product? Where are you going to use that… Give your real plugin related minimal code in your question… You did not [really search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+product+category)

Comment: Hello, if the category is equal to the quotes (xxxxx). I want to work my own custom code in the "if" section. If it is not equal to "if" section I want to run other codes.
So that i need the php code of "product category"

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions? Anyways you should give your real plugin related minimal code in your question…